# Array.pop() not returning all letters in reversing function

Tags: javascript

I'm currently practising on Codewars, and I've come across a strange issue using the .pop() method. While attempting to reverse the letters in each word in a given string, while maintaining each words position and each space, I am attempting to use a nested for loop to access each letter in each word separately, and pop the last letter off of each word after splitting the words into separate arrays. Here is my code:

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  let val = ''
  let newStr = str.split(/(\s+)/)
  for(let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
    let pieces = newStr[i].split('');
    for(let j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++){
      val += pieces.pop()
    }
  }
  return val
}
```

When I do this, I am losing a certain number of letters in each word, and I'm not sure why. For example, when given the string `'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'` I return `'eh kci nwo xo spm re eh yz .g'` I can't seem to wrap my head around why pop is missing the final letter or letters in each word.

I have also tried

```
function reverseWords(str) {
  let val = ''
  let newStr = str.split(/(\s+)/)
  for(let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < newStr[i].length; j++){
      val += newStr[i].split('').pop()
    }
  }
  return val
}
```

but this only returns the final letter of each word * the length of the word.

Comment: `pop` is mutating the array it is called on.

Comment: As an experiment, you can replace the inner loop in your first example with this version: `for(let j = pieces.length-1; j > -1; j--){ ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mutating the array by `.pop`ping it *while you're iterating over it*. So, for example, if the array originally contains 4 elements, then in the following code:

```
for(let j = 0; j < pieces.length; j++){
  val += pieces.pop()
}
```

This is what happens:

- j starts at 0
- you remove the last element from the array (array now contains 3 elements)
- j is incremented to 1
- you remove the last element from the array (array now contains 2 elements)
- j is incremented to 2
- Loop ends (because `j < pieces.length` -> `2 < 2` condition fails)

The words that were originally at positions 0 and 1 do not get popped and concatenated with `val`.

Change the condition to `while (pieces.length)`:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let val = ''
  let newStr = str.split(/(\s+)/)
  for(let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
    let pieces = newStr[i].split('');
    while (pieces.length) {
      val += pieces.pop()
    }
  }
  return val
}

console.log(reverseWords('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'));
```

Or, much more concisely, use a regular expression to match word characters, and have a replacer function `.reverse()` them:

```js
const reverseWords = str => str.replace(
  /\w+/g,
  word => [...word].reverse().join('')
);

console.log(reverseWords('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'));
```

(not sure if you want the `.` to be reversed with the words or not)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the alternate solution. I'm still in the process of understanding all of the regex syntax, so it is still a bit foreign to me. For the moment I'm going to stick with loops.

Comment: I do have one question, why does the while loop not mutate the full string even though pop is being used in the same way as in the for loop?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're already using a regex with `/(\s+)/` (which, in `.split`, is *more* complicated than `.match`ing `\w+` IMO)

Comment: You're not popping (or shifting) pieces out of the `newStr` while you're iterating over it, so the problem does not arise - the `newStr` array remains static. (though `newStr` is an odd name for a variable which is not a string, maybe call it `origWordsArr` instead?)

Comment: So basically with the for loop, as the j variable increases to the point of being greater than the length of pieces, the length of pieces is decreasing at the same rate since .pop() is mutating each 'piece' if you will. The while loop doesn't have the counter iterating up toward the diminishing length, so it is able to access the full value of the 'piece' it is iterating through.

Thanks a ton for your help, makes sense and is a great lesson learned in proper loop usage.